# How can I properly change the node for a CKEditor instance?

Tags: ckeditor

I am using ckeditor for my app, which allows users to create rich text contents. My page may contain several editor areas(textareas replaced by ckeditor), but only one is editable at a time, when a user double click on a editor area, that becomes editable and others are readonly.  My current approach is when double clicking a text area, create a new CKEDITOR.editor instance, when double clicking a different one, call editor.destroy() to destroy existing one and recreate a new for the other textarea. My concern is it may causes a lot of overhead when frequently recreating ckeditor instances as even a single creation of it is expensive.

What I want to achieve is to have only one global ckeditor instance, 'attach' it to the selected textarea on double click. I've tried moving an existing ckeditor.container(the editor widget wrapper) to be within a different node, but then it throws the following errors in firefox :[image]

**what is the proper way to move a ckeditor to within a different node, please?**

Any pointer will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not answering the question but suggesting an alternate route; would shared spaces for CKE work for you? [Link](http://nightly.ckeditor.com/7594/_samples/sharedspaces.html)

Comment: that's a big hint! looks it is one way of solving my problem, will give it a try. thanks a lot.